# Fedora 21: Cannot Ping or Curl, but can Access Internet

Tags: yum, fedora, certificate-authority

We have an automatic proxy server configuration setup, and I can use a web browser but ping/curl are failing; it looks like a DNS resolution problem.

When I do:

```
URLGRABBER_DEBUG=1 yum check-update
```

Everything seems peach until this:

> NSS error -8172 (SEC_ERROR_UNTRUSTED_ISSUER)
>   Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.

I have tried a few things, but I'm no network Jedi; could someone with a better understanding of the Force help me out, here?

Thanks!

Comment: You may be under a MITM attack. What "few things" have you tried? What are the configs and tracing results?

Comment: I think my corporate proxy looks like a MITM attack because they are doing something funny with their certs (either incorrectly, or in the process of monitoring all traffic). I've tried adding Google's nameserver's to my resolve.conf, I use "proxy=..." and pick one of the IP addresses rather than use automatic proxy configuration, I've made a few other changes (with increasingly less understanding of network 'stuff').

Comment: The _automatic proxy server configuration setup_ may be "blocking".  Have you asked your "keepers of the network" to enable your access?

Comment: Yes, I already have network access over port 80; My browser works just fine. There's some other cert problem.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are pretty good that your corporate IT folks are signing their own certs (and intercepting all traffic, etc.).  If you don't think they are evil, you could try adding ...

```
sslverify=0
```

in

```
/etc/yum.conf
```

and then hopefully `yum` will "just work", though less securely.